# How to copy table without primary key to another one

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to copy one table to another one.

For example I have table `Data(ID, time, serial_number...)` and I have `Temp_data(ID, time, serial_number...)`

How to copy all items without primary key (`ID`).

I am using MYSQL,
I have tried `INSERT INTO Data SELECT * FROM Temp_data;`

Problem is in primary key. both of the tables already have values and I need everything to be copied except ID.

Comment: Is PK an iden that auto increments?

Comment: Then that is why you need to select the other columns and leave the iden out.  See the answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `SELECT *`, spell out the columns that you want:

```
INSERT INTO Data (time, serial_number...)
  SELECT (time, serial_number...) FROM Temp_data;
```

Comment: I don't know how it is with MySQL, but in PostgreSQL you will get an error when you use the parenthesis around the fields to select. It would be correct without: `INSERT INTO Data (time, serial_number...) SELECT time, serial_number... FROM Temp_data;`

Comment: @eggyal How to do it if I want to insert the selected columns a few records at a time? eg if I want to insert 5000 rows at a time, how do I do it?

Comment: @pravinnavle: you can add a `WHERE` clause to the `SELECT`, eg `WHERE id BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000` or `WHERE created >= '2018-01-01' AND created < '2019-01-01'` etc—but I can’t really think of any reason one would ever want to chunk the insertion in this way, especially since the source table could get updated between chunks resulting in inconsistent data unless you’re careful...

Comment: actually I have a table which doesn't have a primary key and doesn't even have any field related to date and I wanted to copy the data from this table to another table on a different server. sql dump would do the job but i wanted to copy few rows at a time

Comment: @pravinnavle: those were just examples.  Use whatever columns you have.

Answer (score 7):

You have to define the columns name in your query otherwise it will insert all the columns

```
INSERT INTO tbl2 (column1, column2)
    SELECT tbl1.col1, tbl1.col2 FROM tbl1
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a really annoying problem since every time you need to update the columns, you also need to update the code that copies them. Here's the solution I use to get around the problem and future-proof the code:

```sql
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempData;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempData (LIKE Data);
    
    INSERT INTO TempData SELECT * FROM Data;
    
    ALTER TABLE TempData CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NULL, DROP PRIMARY KEY;
    UPDATE TempData SET id = 0;
    
    INSERT INTO Data SELECT * FROM TempData;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempData;
```

Fast, easy and once written, providing the source table name is the same, works every time.